# Microsoft Graph API 'any' filter applied to Contacts

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to query contacts from Azure AD using MS Graph API and filter to retrieve only those that have at least one phone number defined, so I tried with this filter:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/contacts?$filter=phones/any(a:a/number ne '')
```

According to Microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#any-operator) at least how I understood it, it should return all contacts which have property 'phone' which has at least one sub-property 'number' not empty string (I tried with ne null or even some specific number e.g. ne '12345', resulting error is the same).

I have the "ConsistencyLevel" header set to "eventual".

Error I'm getting is:

```
Expect simple name=value query, but observe property 'phones' of complex type 'Phone'.
```

Phones property is indeed an array of objects:

```
"phones": [
            {
                "number": null,
                "type": "businessFax"
            },
            {
                "number": null,
                "type": "mobile"
            },
            {
                "number": null,
                "type": "business"
            }
        ]
```

So what am I missing here (I admit I am new to MS Graph and don't know all the quirks)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http#organizational-contacts-properties) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/orgcontact?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) `phones` property is not filterable and it does not matter whether `ConsistencyLevel` header is set or not.